# SQLite3: Remove duplicates

Tags: sqlite, duplication

Given the following table

```
CREATE TABLE `sms` (
    `_id`   INTEGER,
    `thread_id` INTEGER,
    `address`   TEXT,
    `person`    INTEGER,
    `date`  INTEGER,
    `protocol`  INTEGER,
    `read`  INTEGER DEFAULT 0,
    `status`    INTEGER DEFAULT -1,
    `type`  INTEGER,
    `reply_path_present`    INTEGER,
    `subject`   TEXT,
    `body`  TEXT,
    `service_center`    TEXT,
    PRIMARY KEY(_id)
);
```

I'd like to delete all rows where `address` and `body` are identical. In other words, eliminate dups based on `address` and `body`, leaving only the first occurrence.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you just want to disambiguate two rows with similar content, you can use the [ROWID](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#rowid) functionality in SQLite3, which helps uniquely identify each row in the table.

Something like this:

`DELETE FROM sms WHERE rowid NOT IN (SELECT min(rowid) FROM sms GROUP BY address, body);`

should work to get you the rows with the minimum rowid, which will be the first occurrence of that row in the table.

Be sure to run this in a transaction however, to make sure that it does exactly what you want, and of course, take a backup beforehand. =)

Answer (score 1):

SQLite has had [window functions](https://www.sqlite.org/windowfunctions.html) since 3.25.0 which are extremely cool, a bit tricky to grasp, and useful for this task.

You can do something like:

```sql
delete from sms
where rowid in (
  select rowid
  from (
    select
      rowid,
      row_number() over (
        partition by address, body
        -- order by some_expression
        ) as n
    from sms
  )
  where n > 1
);
```

Less compact but potentially more powerful than normal `group by`.

You could factor out the innermost `select` into a view if you wanted to check its behaviour before running `delete`!